# NoClassDefFoundError when using Spring Boot modules loaded from PropertiesLoader by IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, classloader

I have an application which has a Spring Boot core which can have optional modules added at runtime (using PropertiesLoader).

```
-Dloader.main=com.mycompany.App
-Dloader.path="C:\dir\some-module.jar"
```

The modules are packaged as fat jars, so they have all of their dependencies bundled with them. I use the shade plugin for this.

One of the additional modules has a dependency on JDBC and when I unzip its JAR, I can see that the Hikari stuff is present.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I run the application from the JAR everything works. However, when I run from IntellIJ's classpath, one of the Hikari classes fails to load.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceJmxConfiguration$Hikari
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:447) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.App.main(App.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[spring-boot-loader-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[spring-boot-loader-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-loader-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:593) ~[spring-boot-loader-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2626b418]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:686) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:583) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:568) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:626) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:738) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:679) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:647) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:195) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:159) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:152) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:140) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:135) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:97) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:298) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:289) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:278) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:189) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:138) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2314) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:668) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

When I put a breakpoint here in `org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher`

```
protected void launch(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JarFile.registerUrlProtocolHandler();
    ClassLoader classLoader = this.createClassLoader(this.getClassPathArchives());
    this.launch(args, this.getMainClass(), classLoader); //breakpoint 
}
```

I can see that the `LaunchedURLClassLoader` is created correctly (i.e. it has a reference to the module JAR) and when I evaluate

```
classLoader.loadClass("com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource")
```

in the debugger, I can see that the class can be loaded fine from here.

When `DataSourceJmxConfiguration$Hikari` is loaded, however, it loads with a parent classloader since the Spring Boot Auto-Configure is bundled into the core Spring Boot app. When Spring attempts to call `getDeclaredMethods`, it blows up since `HikariDataSource` needs to be loaded by the child classloader, and the parent is not aware of any of it's children.

`HikariDataSource` is certainly on the classpath since `DataSourceJmxConfiguration$Hikari` is conditional upon it being there

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({HikariDataSource.class})
@ConditionalOnSingleCandidate(DataSource.class)
static class Hikari {
    //...
}
```

I wasn't able to determine what was different about running directly from the JAR, and why that works over what IntelliJ is doing. I can see that the the initial classloader is created in what looks to be the same way.

This problem unfortunately does not lend itself to posting a reproducible example here (I *could* but you would have to construct the entire project structure yourself). Instead, I have created [a MCVE on GitHub](https://github.com/michaelboyles/jdbc-autoconfigure-failure) - it is only 5 files, 3 of which are POMs.

What's the difference with regards to how these classes are loaded, and how can I fix it?

I could continue to run as a 'JAR Application', which works, but it is more convenient to run as an 'Application', since then I can do a hot replace and I do not need to build a new JAR for every change. I would also just like to know for my own understanding.

Comment: Using your github I failed here already: `Unable to open nested entry 'org/h2/util/data.zip'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file`

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn When running it using which of the run configs?

Answer (score 1):

I have check the java command that Intellij running (it is written in the 1st line in the run window, you can copy it and check it), and when you run it as application, Intellij programmatically add the -classpath options in the java command. And in the classpath, the jdbc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar does not exists (neither any jar that seems to contains the class needed). So I added this configuration your configuration (the "Test (failing)" one)

```
-Dloader.main=com.mycompany.App
-Dloader.path=C:\Java\jdbc-autoconfigure-failure\jdbc\target\shaded\jdbc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
-classpath $Classpath$
```

and it worked. Because it seem the option -classpath $Classpath$ reload the classpath using the project -classpath VM options and load the HikariCP-3.2.0.jar. You can either use the solution or add the jdbc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in the "core" module setting in dependencies tab.

EDIT:
This is the configuration that should be use for running as Application. First add all library needed for spring-boot in lib folder inside working directory, you can find all jars needed for spring-boot in BOOT-INF\lib inside core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. In this example I am copying all jars needed into C:\Java\jdbc-autoconfigure-failure\core\lib

```
-Dloader.main=com.mycompany.App
-Dloader.path="C:\Java\jdbc-autoconfigure-failure\core\lib,C:\Java\jdbc-autoconfigure-failure\core\target\classes,C:\Java\jdbc-autoconfigure-failure\jdbc\target\shaded\jdbc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
-classpath "C:\Java\jdbc-autoconfigure-failure\core\lib\spring-boot-loader-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar"
```

EDIT:
Found the issue

```
-Dloader.main=com.mycompany.App
-Dloader.path=\"C:\Java\jdbc-autoconfigure-failure\jdbc\target\shaded\jdbc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\"
```

Comment: "And in the classpath, the jdbc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar does not exists (neither any jar that seems to contains the class needed)" That's because it shouldn't need to be on the classpath. It's on Spring's loader path.

Comment: In my opinion the issue came because running 'Application' with org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher as main class that came from a jar give an impact between loader path and classpath that make it a must to include the jars needed into classpath. I have fixed my answer too, the jar needed is HikariCP-3.2.0.jar.

Comment: I have found the configuration that should be use for running as Application. I have added it to my answer.

Comment: I also think that the issue came because the "C:\Java\jdbc-autoconfigure-failure\core\target\classes" was in the classpath not in loader path

Comment: This is a workaround, but it does not really answer the fundamental question of *why*. Like I said in my question, the class is clearly on the classpath, even without `-classpath` (since I evaluated `classLoader.loadClass(...)`
). The issue is from which classloader it is loaded.

Comment: I found the issue, check my answer. It was so simple.

Comment: -Dloader.path=\"C:\Java\jdbc-autoconfigure-failure\jdbc\target\shaded\jdbc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\"   add \ before "

Comment: Why do you think the escapes are required? The module is certainly included without them, since the autoconfiguration is conditional upon `HikariDataSource`. Why would escaping them make any difference to the classloader?

Comment: I have tried using intelllij IDEA ultimate, and it is working using intellij IDEA ultimate, and I found that is the difference that run in ultimate. And I added it to your command and it is running. May be the difference is the way java read the options between jar and class

Comment: in your setting the jdbc-1.0.SNAPSHOT.jar is not loaded. The ```org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher```, ```LaunchedURLClassLoader```, and ```DataSourceJmxConfiguration$Hikari``` is loaded from the -classpath that intellij added. It is come from the jars ```spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar``` and ```spring-boot-loader-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar```. But when it need to load the ```HikariDataSource```, the ```HikariCP-3.2.0.jar``` is not found.